# Visual Studio 2013 section of menu missing

Tags: visual-studio-2013

When right-clicking a view in my current project, the menu is missing Publish/Preview/Replace options (see link below). I searched Google and StackExchange to no avail. I compared this project settings to another project which DOES have the options and I still can't see what I'm doing wrong. I am not in debug mode and was able to publish individual views in this project previously. I also tried resetting the import/export settings, and also using the keyboard shortcuts, neither or which helped. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

[Image Here!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBITA.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My co-worker answered this question: Earlier today my PublishProfiles in Properties were changed. I reverted them back. Yeah, that was all there was to that...